# Convert docx stream to pdf directly

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2013

I need to convert any file coming from web response into .pdf format, I'm currently getting it word docx file format from the URL and saving it into memory stream so i can later insert it in it's designated library.

The problem I'm facing now is that I'm saving my docx files directly into .pdf by putting an extension at the end which obviously ends up not opening the file later, So i'm trying to convert my memory stream into pdf directly .

Here is my piece of code that i tried to convert the the stream to .pdf but it looks like the file isn't getting converted correctly.

```
private Stream DownloadFromUrl(string url)
        {
            var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            webRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
            webRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            //EventLogUtility.LogInformationMessage(DocumentURL);
            string message = string.Empty;
            using (Stream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
                {

                    using (var content = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        var memory = new MemoryStream();
                        content.CopyTo(memory);
                        Document doc = new Document(memory);
                        doc.Save(memory, SaveFormat.Pdf);
                        return memory;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can't convert them “directly”, neither Word nor PDF are streamable formats. Converting between them is a huge amount of work. Before you go in this direction, work on getting your provider to provide PDF, text, or practically any format other than .docx. If that is impossible, get your consumer to accept Word, text, or any other format. If that is impossible, buy an off-the-shelf document converter. You do not want to build this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If the content in the stream is actually in the Microsoft Word file format (and not just plain text), then you need to map the format to the file format for PDF. I know there is a 'Print to PDF' function available in Word, you could try looking into that.

Comment: I do not have control over the word files coming from the web response, i can't just convert them manually prior getting them from the web response.

Comment: Yes, get the response as they are coming in. But then *after* you get the response, you will need to use a library to convert the data to PDF format. I was suggesting that there is a function to print word documents to a PDF file in Word, perhaps you can look into using that through an API.